# Grouping the rows on the basis of specific condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group the rows on the basis of a specific condition.
The table structure is something like this

```
   EmpID | EmpName | TaskId | A_Shift_Status | B_Shift_Status | C_Shift_Status | D_Shift_Status

    1    | John    |  1     |  1             |    null        |      2         |        1 
    1    | John    |  2     |  1             |    null        |      1         |        1 
    2    | Mike    |  3     |  1             |    1           |      2         |        1 
    2    | Mike    |  4     |  null          |    1           |      null      |        1 
    3    | Steve   |  5     |  null          |    1           |      2         |        1 
    3    | Steve   |  6     |  1             |    null        |      2         |        1
```

```
The criteria will be
Done     1
Pending  2
NA       3
```

The expected output is to group the employees by task and the status will be on the following condition

- if **ALL** tasks are done by any employee then the status will be done
  (i.e. 1)
- if **ANY** of the tasks is incomplete then the status will be
  incomplete/pending (i.e. 2)

So the desired output will be

```
  EmpID | EmpName | A_Shift_Status | B_Shift_Status | C_Shift_Status | D_Shift_Status

   1    | John    |  1             |    null        |      2         |        1 
   2    | Mike    |  1             |    1           |      2         |        1 
   3    | Steve   |  1             |    1           |      2         |        1
```

So in other terms summary/grouping should only show complete/done (i.e. 1) when all the rows of a particular shift column of an employee have status as complete/done (i.e. 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data (where the criteria are 1, 2 and NULL for n/a), a simple 'group by' the employee, and MAX of the columns, should work e.g.,

```
SELECT 
    yt.EmpID, 
    yt.EmpName, 
    MAX(yt.A_Shift_Status) AS A_Shift_Status, 
    MAX(yt.B_Shift_Status) AS B_Shift_Status, 
    MAX(yt.C_Shift_Status) AS C_Shift_Status, 
    MAX(yt.D_Shift_Status) AS D_Shift_Status
FROM
    yourtable yt
GROUP BY
    yt.EmpID,
    yt.EmpName;
```

For the shift statuses

- If any of them are 2, it returns 2
- otherwise if any of them are 1, it returns 1
- otherwise it returns NULL

Notes re 1/2/3 (which was specified as criteria) vs 1/2/NULL (which is in the data)

- It gets a little tricker if the inputs are supposed to use 1/2/3 instead of 1/2/NULL. Let us know if you are changing the inputs to reflect that.
- If the input is fine as NULLs, but you need the output to have '3' for n/a (nulls), you can put an ISNULL or COALESCE around the MAX statements e.g., `ISNULL(MAX(yt.A_Shift_Status), 3) AS A_Shift_Status`

Comment: This grouping will not work because any of the statuses is 1 (complete) then it will return 1 That means any of the tasks from the shift is not completed then the summary/grouping status should show status as incomplete. Or in other terms summary/grouping should only show complete/done (i.e. 1)  when all the rows pertaining to an employee have status as complete/done (i.e. 1)

Comment: My answer gives exactly the same results as your desired output - see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d13b45fb06e10f6720093e62a960b3f4  - if any tasks are incomplete it returns 2, even if others are 1.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But what if the shift columns are not fixed. it may have 2 shifts columns for all employees or may have 4 shifts. Note: There is one master for a shift that provides the exact shift count.

Comment: Assuming your columns are 'fixed' within the database (e.g., your table structure is what you have said in the question) then I presume the people with 2 shifts would have NULLs for shifts C and D. In those situations, this approach will return NULLs as well (similar to John's B-shift in example data/output).

Comment: Actually, this is a temp table that gets generated runtime (the table structure from the question) so the shift columns are NOT fixed.

Comment: Some options a) If the table is being created dynamically (e.g., via dynamic SQL) you could use a similar approach to dyamically create the SELECT statements b) If it's always 2 or 4 shifts, then have separate code for each c) have the table with the largest columns, populate all columns as above, then report on the ones you want either dynamic SQL select, or separate statements IF @NumCols = 2 SELECT ..., A_shift_status, B_Shift_status; Alternatives depend on how you are creating your table - it may be better in a new question.

Comment: @GaneshParikh . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, then as a *new* question.  And you should probably accept this answer as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Accepted this answer.@seanb thank I have done it using the dynamic sql